# Using Fourier Series of $|x|$ to find $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I found the Fourier series of $f(x) = |x|$ to be $$f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2 \cos(nx) \frac{-1 + (-1)^n}{\pi n^2}$$

> Taking $x = 0$, prove that a) $$ \sum_{n: odd \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ and b) $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Problem a) is easy is to show if you assume changing the index of $n$ does not change the equality (which it should). In that case you obtain $$0 = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{n:odd \geq 1} \frac{-4}{\pi n^2} \rightarrow \sum_{n:odd \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8} $$ But the Fourier series representation I found for $f$ has a sum over all $n \geq 1$ and not just the odd $n$.

For problem b) Im not sure what to do about the $(-1)^n$ term in the numerator.

Comment: For (a), note that the $-1+(-1)^n$ annihilates all the even $n$ terms, so your sum is over the odd $n$ only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About a), you get only odd $n$'s because $-1+(-1) ^n$ is zero for even $n$!

About $(b) $, if you define

$$A= \sum_{n \ge 1 \text{ even}} \frac{1}{n^2} ,\ \ \  B =\sum_{n\ge 1 \text{ odd}} \frac{1}{n^2} $$

Then you have, setting $n=2m$ for $n$ even:

$$ A = \sum_{\ge 1 \text{ even}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{m\ge 1 } \frac{1}{4 m^2} = \frac{1}{4} ( A+B) $$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I was able to finish using this hint. However if Im correct this means $$\sum_{n \ge 1 \text{ even}} = \frac{\pi^2}{24}$$ While $$\sum_{n\ge 1 \text{ odd}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ Should they not be equal since there are as many even numbers as there are odd ones?

Comment: No, because even are smaller than odds. Indeed, note that $A=(A+B) /4$ contributes for 1/4 of the total sum. If you backtrace where the 1/4 come from, it's because $1/(2n) ^2 = 1/4n^2$. Quadraticity makes small numbers contribute way less. If it was linear you'd have a $1/2$ as you expected.